# When using SOSL to query toLabel(), the data queried in the Console is inconsistent with the anonymous code

Tags: apex, lightning

Does anyone know the reason for this?

**SOSL Query**

```
FIND {搜索测试} RETURNING Account(Id,Name, toLabel(SalesOrganization2__c))
```

[image]

**Anonymous code**

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND '搜索测试' RETURNING Account(Id,Name, toLabel(SalesOrganization2__c))];
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'searchList = ' + searchList);
```

[image]

Comment: Does this code work fine when executed in an apex class? I've seem some weird behaviors like this in anonymous apex execution (by 'weird', I mean it would start giving the expected results after some time or vice-versa).

Comment: Hi @arut The result of the execution in the APEX class is consistent with the result of the anonymous code.

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the field in SOSL query? I don't think this would work, but doesn't hurt to give it a try. I remember something like this SOQL query but don't remember where I saw it.

Comment: Also, you may have tried the following (if not, then give it a try): (1) Run a SOQL query for the same in the same apex code to check the output. Just thinking on the lines of underlying query mechanism having some issue or lag in SOQL vs SOSL. (2) Does this query give you the expected language in its result? `[SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]`

Comment: Hi @arut  I tried to use the SOSL to label() alias in APEX, but it prompts an error when saving.
I have given up on solving this problem because it took me too much time.
I finally chose to use SOQL tolabel().

Comment: OK. It would be good to know why this is happening or if this local to the specific org you are using. So, if you get time and are willing to, then try it out on a different org with different field.